# JavaFx won't download on my MacBook Pro for Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, javafx

I have an assignment for my school that I have to submit that needs you to create a Java application that involves recursion, file read, and javaFx. I have a 15 inch MacBook Pro with an i7 processor. When I try to use JavaFx in a class in Java, I always get errors saying that javaFx.application.Application or javaFx.scene.Scene cannot be applied to a type. Basically, my Java oxygen application cannot run javaFx. I've tried multiple YouTube videos on how to download plugins from oracle and the Java oxygen marketplace. I told my instructor and he hasn't gotten back to me yet. Everytime I download a possible plugin like e(fx)clipse/2.0.0/ (or something like that), Java oxygen sends a message that it cannot complete the operation because new software has already been installed. I kept searching oracle for the latest JDK but javaFx still won't download. I was just wondering if it had to do with me having an Apple and not Windows computer or is there something else I can try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Describe what have you done so far.

Comment: After notifying my instructor, I began searching for downloads in the eclipse marketplace. I kept getting the same error message of new software already being installed on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just go here and download the Mac version of the JDK and install it.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html
That is all which is technically needed to run a JavaFX application. You should also download and install the latest version of Eclipse (Photon) because it fixes some problems with the latest Java.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php
If you like you can also install e(fx)clipse from the marketplace but it is not needed to write JavaFX applications.